# How come my conditional branches won't print even though the Booleans are in place?

Tags: python, printing, boolean

I made a very simple, silly program just for practice. How come the last part doesn't print what I want it to print?

```
string1=input("Write any food that begins with the letter 'a'")
string1.lower()

if string1.startswith("a")==True:
  print("Good job")
elif string1.startswith("a")==False:
  print("Are you sure you know what the letter 'a' is?")

string2=input("Now, write any food that ends with 'b'.")
string2.lower()

if string2.endswith("b")==True:
  print("That's right!")
elif string2.endswith("b")==False:
  print("No, that's not right.")

fruits=input("Now, enter five different fruits, separated by commas.\n")
fruits.split(",")
list1=[fruits]

print("Now, let's see if %s is in this list"%string1)

if string1 in list1==True:
  print("Yes, it is")
elif string1 in list1==False:
  print("No, it isn't.")

print("Now, let's see if %s is in this list"%string2)

if string2 in list1==True:
  print("Good work")
elif string2 in list1==False: 
  print("Not true")
```

No matter what I write, "good work" and "not true" and "yes, it is" etc. won't print. Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: the way you have used split is wrong. All you need to do is `list1=fruits.split(",")`. Split method returns a list.

Comment: Why are you doing `if x in y==True:`? Just do `if x in y:`.

Answer (score 1):

### Break down the problem

Let's go step by step:

1. `if string1 in list1==True:`

First thing evaluated is `list1 == True` which will return `False` because `list1` does not equal `True`

Now we have this:

2. `if string1 in False:`

This will return False because `string1` is not in the boolean `False`

So all of your statements will return False

---

### The Fix?

1. `if string1 in list1:`

Simply remove `==True` or `==False` from your statements.

If you want to evaluate false use `not` instead.

i.e. `if string1 not in list1:` or you could say `if not (string1 in list1):`

Hope this helps! Leave a comment if you have questions.

---

## A few more tweaks later

Try this

```py
string1=input("Write any food that begins with the letter 'a'")
string1.lower()

if string1.startswith("a")==True:
  print("Good job")
elif string1.startswith("a")==False:
  print("Are you sure you know what the letter 'a' is?")

string2=input("Now, write any food that ends with 'b'.")
string2.lower()

if string2.endswith("b")==True:
  print("That's right!")
elif string2.endswith("b")==False:
  print("No, that's not right.")

fruits=input("Now, enter five different fruits, separated by commas.\n")
fruits = fruits.split(",")
list1=[fruit.strip(' ') for fruit in fruits]

print("Now, let's see if %s is in this list"%string1)

if string1 in list1:
  print("Yes, it is")
elif string1 not in list1:
  print("No, it isn't.")

print("Now, let's see if %s is in this list"%string2)

if string2 in list1:
  print("Good work")
elif string2 not in list1: 
  print("Not true")
```

Things to note, when you made your list how you made it, and then split by commas, you accidentally had an extra space ' ' after each word, so even if you check if 'apple' is in the list and it IS in the list, it would return false because 'apple ' would be in the list (note the space).  This is what the `fruit.strip(' ')` line is taking care of.

Comment: Though removing the `== True` part solves the problem, your explanation is wrong.  The reason for the OP's problem is that `in` and `==` have the same precedence, so `string1 in list1 == True` is chained comparisons, and is evaluated as `(string1 in list1)  and (list1 == True)` (see [The documentation about comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)).

Comment: So, `string1 in list1` will always be evaluated first. If it is `False`, the whole expression will be `False` and work as expected, by 'chance'. Only if it is `True`will the second part `list1 == ...` need to be evaluated, and will be `False` because the list is not equal to a boolean, as you explained.

Comment: Feel free to edit that into your answer ;)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille How have I not noticed this before? Good catch.  Feel free to edit the answer as you see fit and I'll accept the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you dont have to check True, False

```
if string2 in list1:
  print("Good work")
else: 
  print("Not true")
```